# stripe webhook implementation returns 400 dotnet core razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, stripe-payments, webhooks, razor-pages

Hi All I'm trying to get the strip webhooks to work keep getting return 400 any help appreciated.

S D:\Projects\xxxxx> stripe listen --forward-to https://localhost:44331/webhook --latest

> Ready! You are using Stripe API Version [2020-08-27]. Your webhook signing secret is whsec_xxxxxxxx (^C to quit)
> 2021-12-08 14:38:29   --> charge.succeeded [evt_3K4HvEFu7HTEUmJb0uREPAjf]
> 2021-12-08 14:38:29  <--  [400] POST https://localhost:44331/webhook [evt_3K4HvEFu7HTEUmJb0uREPAjf]
> 2021-12-08 14:38:29   --> payment_intent.succeeded [evt_3K4HvEFu7HTEUmJb0PWxB4XR]
> 2021-12-08 14:38:29  <--  [400] POST https://localhost:44331/webhook [evt_3K4HvEFu7HTEUmJb0PWxB4XR]
> 2021-12-08 14:38:29   --> payment_intent.created [evt_3K4HvEFu7HTEUmJb0E7a2Ic7]
> 2021-12-08 14:38:29  <--  [400] POST https://localhost:44331/webhook [evt_3K4HvEFu7HTEUmJb0E7a2Ic7]

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Stripe;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using xxxx.Models;
using xxxx.Services.Interfaces;
using xxxx.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace xxxxxxx.Pages
{
public class WebHookModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IOptions<StripeOptions> options;

    private readonly IUserSubscriptionRepository _userSubscription;
    public WebHookModel(IOptions<StripeOptions> options,
        IUserSubscriptionRepository userSubscription)
    {
        this.options = options;
        _userSubscription = userSubscription;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public UserSubscription UserSubscription { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Api Post called");

        var json = await new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        Event stripeEvent;

        

        try
        {
            stripeEvent = EventUtility.ConstructEvent(
                json,
                Request.Headers["Stripe-Signature"],
                this.options.Value.WebhookSecret
            );
            Console.WriteLine($"Webhook notification with type: {stripeEvent.Type} found for {stripeEvent.Id}");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Something failed {e}");
            return BadRequest();
        }


        try
        {



            switch (stripeEvent.Type)
            {
                case Events.CustomerSubscriptionCreated:
                    var subscription = stripeEvent.Data.Object as UserSubscription;
                    _userSubscription.Add(subscription);
                    break;

                case Events.CustomerSubscriptionUpdated:
                    var update = stripeEvent.Data.Object as UserSubscription;
                    _userSubscription.Update(update);
                    break;

                case Events.CustomerCreated:
                    var customer = stripeEvent.Data.Object as UserSubscription;
                    _userSubscription.Add(customer);
                    break;
                default:
                    Debug.WriteLine("Default case");
                    break;
            }

            return new StatusCodeResult(200);
        }
        catch (StripeException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message);
            return BadRequest();
        }
        
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You are returning 400 error codes in your exception handlers. Is there an error message written to the console? If not, you are likely failing request verification: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/security/request-verification

Comment: Similarly, your code returns a 400 if Stripe signature verification fails. It looks like you are using Stripe's demo so if that is failing I would double check that your webhook secret variable is populated and is the correct secret for the WH you are getting events from. https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures

Comment: Mike Brind There is no message in the console and you are spot on it is failing validation. I should have realized that as I have had that issue before  with Razor Pages, Oh will I ever learn. After adding [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken(Order = 1001)] to the page it works. I read in the article on learn razor pages that the recommended way to accept post requests from an outside source is to add a controller maybe I will take a look at that instead of using a razor page. Thanks for the help much appreciated.